# Where in LGA Terminal B can one buy a Metro Card?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, new-york-city, lga

In the old Terminal B there was a large machine inside the terminal near the stop for the city buses that sold metro cards.  I do not know where that machine is in the new terminal B.  Without a metro card, you can only pay the $2.75 with coins (not bills and not credit card) which is not user friendly.

Update: Buses now allow use of credit cards upon boarding.

Comment: It used to be the case that there were no Metrocard vending machines at LGA, so people arriving from out of town who wished to use a bus but not to pay with coins were advised to buy one from the newsstand inside the terminal. As Jon Custer notes, there are now vending machines available, but you could consider a newsstand as a backup plan if needed.

Comment: Do MTA buses not accept contactless credit/debit cards now? I know they were rolloing out OMNY (contactless) terminals across the entire subway/bus system, but as I don't have to commute into NYC these days, not sure how far into the program they are.

Comment: Metrocards are 1980s technology. They were scheduled to be gone by July 2023, but currently they are scheduled to be gone by 2024. Use the new OMNY system instead. If you have a near field communication capable mobile phone, you should be able to set it up on https://omny.info/ to pay with it for MTA's bus or subway. Otherwise, get an OMNY card for $5. Also, as mlc notes, the Q70 bus is currently free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jon Custer writes, there are now Metrocard vending machines in the terminals. However, there are additional options for getting on a bus from LGA:

- All MTA buses and subways now accept payment via contactless credit cards or smartphone mobile wallets (e.g. Android Pay and Apple Pay) via the [OMNY system](https://omny.info/).
- The Q70 bus (the [“LaGuardia Link”](https://new.mta.info/guides/airports/laguardia)) is now *free*—no payment required or even possible—and offers nonstop service between the airport and the Jackson Heights subway station, from which you can continue your journey by easily purchasing a Metrocard or by paying directly with OMNY as discussed above.

Answer (score 7):

From [the La Guardia site](https://www.laguardiaairport.com/to-from-airport/public-transportation) one finds

> MetroCards can be purchased at MetroCard vending machines located throughout LaGuardia Airport terminals. Passengers using MetroCards get a free transfer from their bus to the subway.

Going to [their maps](https://www.laguardiaairport.com/at-airport/airport-maps) you can click and get an interactive map with search capability. Zoom in on Terminal B, and in the upper left search menu start typing 'Metro' which will autosuggest 'MetroCard Kiosk'. Hit enter and it will show:
[image: MetroCard Kiosk]

One presumes the other terminals have ones as well, just use their search engine.